# How to obtain an url string by concatenating two strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to send a request using **axios**, and it works well when I hardcode the url, like this:

```
const logIn = (email, password) => {
  axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token_auth/", {
    username: email,
    password: password
  })
  .then(function (Response) {
    console.log('Login succesfull');
  })
  .catch(function (Error) {
    console.log('Login failed.');
  });
}
```

The problem is when I try to concatenate two strings to get the same url, like this:

```
import apiServer from 'controllers/settings';

const logIn = (email, password) => {
  axios.post(apiServer+"token_auth/", {
    username: email,
    password: password
  })
  .then(function (Response) {
    console.log('Login succesfull');
  })
  .catch(function (Error) {
    console.log('Login failed.');
  });
}
```

In this later case, I can see that the concatenation is not working straightforwardly, and so I don't get the url string I am looking for:

[image]

Is there any other way in javascript to concatenate two strings so I can use the resulting string as a url?

**EDIT**

The value of apiServer is defined in another file `settings.js`:

```
const apiServer = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/";
```

Comment: `apiServer` is apparently an object. You need a string.

Comment: can u show us how do u build `apiServer` ?

Comment: @MisterJojo https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: Did you try this apiServer.concat("token_auth/")

Comment: Try this "/token_auth/"  instead of "token_auth/"

Comment: What does a console log of apiServer gives you before your post request ?

Comment: @MisterJojo what **axios** actually is has very little, if anything, to do with the improper string concatentation and has every thing to do with the value of `apiServer`

Comment: @Brewal I get `{}`, but I don't know why

Comment: @HuLuViCa well, where do you define it ? You should provide your actual code

Comment: @Taplar I posted the whole content of  `settings.js` (it contains only one line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `export` your constant in you settings.js file :

```
export const apiServer = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/";
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `apiServer` is an Object for some reason.

Just make sure it's a String, and later you can do the concatenation, or a String **interpolation** as follows:

```js
const apiServer = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/"

const url = `${apiServer}token_auth`

console.log(url)
```

If you prefer doing it with **concatenation**:

```
const apiServer = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/"

const url = apiServer + "token_auth"
```